# Importing toolbox and using one of its tools in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, toolbox

I have a python script where I need to import a toolbox which contains a number of tools so that I can use one of them.

.............

Name of the toolbox: Generic_Tools.tbx

Alias of the toolbox: GenericToolbox

Name of the module I need to use: MyTool

.............

And these are the python lines I am trying with to import the toolbox and use the tool:

#Importing

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r'..............\Generic_Tools.tbx')
```

#Using the tool

```
arcpy.GenericToolbox.MyTool("TempLayer", buffer_fc, buffer_dist, "Meters", OutputWorkspace, "false")
```

When I run the script it doesn't throw any error, but the tool MyTool is not run at all. Basically, the line where I am calling the module is just skipped.

In ArcMap this is all working fine. I use the following line to call the tool:

```
arcpy.MyTool("TempLayer", buffer_fc, buffer_dist, "Meters", OutputWorkspace, "false")
```

But if I try with that same line in ArcGIS Pro, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'MyTool'
```

Comment: Review the [code sample](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/multiple-ring-buffer.htm#C_GUID-34A05DCB-8CE1-4420-ABA6-CDDD375770E5) for the tool to see what you are missing.

Comment: MultiRingBuffer is my own python script, not the arcpy standard tool. This works all fine with ArcMap. When trying to move it to ArcGIS Pro I can't seem to get it running.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from not calling the tool properly, but I am not sure.

Comment: While most tools/toolboxes built in ArcMap are compatible with ArcPro, sometimes tweaking is required. (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/faq.htm#anchor51). That final AttributeError suggests there might also be an issue with importing the tool - it didn't import properly therefore it can't be recognized/used later on.

Comment: Are the the tools in your Generic_Tools.tbx _model_ tools, _script_ tools or a mixture?

Comment: They are script tools. In fact, I have deleted al the other tools and left the one I am trying to use. It's a python script. I have run it through "Analyze Tools For Pro" and the result is "No problems".

Comment: Could anyone confirm what's the right way (at least in theory) to call the tool from python after importing the toolbox? In ArcMap is simply arcpy.MyTool(.....).

Comment: So I just ran the following `arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Scratch\cloudburst\BluespotModels_Metric.tbx")` then `arcpy.BMM.IdentifyBluespots(r"C:\scratch\fgdb_scratch.gdb",r"C:\Scratch\cloudburst\Inputs.gdb\DEM","#",r"C:\Scratch\cloudburst\Inputs.gdb\Buildings")` in the python command line window in ArcPro and everything ran OK.

Comment: The model in the toolbox was developed for ArcMap.

Comment: @Hornbydd => BMM is the alias of the toolbox, isn't it?

Comment: Correct BMM is the toolbox alias

Answer (score 0):

Most Toolboxes have an alias option. Sometimes this helps.  Check the properties of the toolbox and set an alias (use a simple code or subject abbreviation).

When calling the tool reference the alias.

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r'..............\Generic_Tools.tbx')
arcpy.MyTool_alias(var1, var2)
```